# Swift: Alamofire Post

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I have been developing an app, and I have to use alamofire to post.
However, I keep getting error, saying

FAILURE
Error: feedback submission failed.
Optional("The operation couldn’t be completed. JSON could not be serialized. Input data was nil or zero length.")

My code looks like this

```
let reportJSON: [String : AnyObject] = [
    "Name" : nameTextField.text!,
    "Message" : reportTextView.text!
  ]
Alamofire.request(.POST, "API", parameters: reportJSON, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON{ response in
    print(response.result)

    guard response.result.error == nil else{
      print("Error: feedback submission failed.")
      print(response.result.error?.localizedDescription)
      return
    }

    if let responseValue = response.result.value{
      let recipeList = JSON(responseValue)
      print(recipeList)
    }
}
```

I had no problem with .GET, but  I cannot figure out the way to use .POST. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I solved this. Maybe it is obvious to other ones, but the data I was receiving was not in JSON format. So instead of responseJSON, I had to use responseData.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're not passing the correct URL instead of "API" change to the valid URL for the post.

Comment: I am using company's private url so for this one, i am just calling API, but in my app, it is using proper url

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following method for POST request using Alamofire and Swift 3:

```
let headers = [
               "Accept": "application/json",
               "Authorization" : "Authorization: Bearer ", //if any
               "Cookie" : "Cookie" //if any
              ]

let parameterDict: NSDictionary = NSDictionary.init(objects: [nameTextField.text!, reportTextView.text!], forKeys: ["Name" as NSCopying,"Message" as NSCopying])

Alamofire.request("API",method: .post, parameters: parameterDict as? [String : AnyObject] , encoding:JSONEncoding.default, headers:headers) .responseJSON {  response in switch response.result {

     case .success(let JSON):
         print("Success with JSON: \(JSON)")
         let response = JSON as! NSDictionary

     case .failure(let error):
         print("Request failed with error: \(error)")


         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code for JSON parsing for post method.

```
   Alamofire.request("URL" , method : .post,
                      headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in
            // do whatever you want here
            switch response.result {
            case .failure(let error): break
                self.popupp(elrtdata : "Please try again latter.")
            case .success(let responseObject):

                if((response.result.value) != nil) {

                    do{
                        let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(response.result.value!)
                        print(swiftyJsonVar) }
```